# how to use combinations() from itertools in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, python-itertools

Is it possible to run itertools from python?

Suppose I have  data rdd like

```
data_rdd = sc.parallelize([(u'a',1),(u'b',1),(u'c',1),(u'c',2),(u'd',2)])
```

I would like to do as these following steps
I would like to extract id on (word,id) to get the list word in same id
( it would extract like ('a','b','c') for id = 1 and ('c','d') =2 )

then run combinations from itertools to find possible combination for each id

the result would be like

```
[((u'a',u'b'),1),((u'a',u'c'),1),((u'b',u'c'),1),((u'c',u'd'),2)]
```

but I have not idea how to use itertools in pyspark

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (RDDs are not iterable) and there is no reason to. All you need is `join` and `filter`.

```
def swap(kv):
    k, v = kv
    return v, k

def is_match(kv):
    _, (v1, v2) = kv
    return v1 < v2

swapped = data_rdd.map(swap)
swapped.join(swapped).filter(is_match).map(swap)
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for [`groupBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy.html) rather than a custom and hard to understand `.filter(is_match).map(swap)`!